# How to know which leaf item were tapped in Nested list?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Who knows is it possible to know which leaf item in NestedList were tapped and use this value in the Store? 
May be I can use `leafitemtap` not only in listeners of NestedList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList-event-leafitemtap

the `leafitemtap` listener function gives you the following params:

`leafitemtap( Ext.dataview.NestedList this, Ext.List list, Number index, Ext.dom.Element target, Ext.data.Record record, Ext.event.Event e, Object eOpts )`

in which:

- `this` points to your current nested list
- `index` is the index of tapped item
- `target` is the DOM element of tapped item
- `record` is the model object of tapped item

Suppose that your model has an `id` field. Then:

`record.get('id')` will return the id of tapped item. You can use this to look it up later in your Store.

Comment: Thank you for reply! but how can I use record.get('id') if my Store is in another file?

Comment: `record.get('id')` is usable right inside your handler function, it returns the `id` of the tapped item. Later, if you want to proceed this `id` with your Store, just use `Ext.getStore('your_store_name')` and then do whatever you want with your store and id

Comment: I'm new to the Sencha and your answers helped me a lot! Thank you very much for your time!